# Expo: Can we use node modules like mqtt.js?

Tags: react-native, expo

If Expo (create-react-native-app) is pure JavaScript, can I use other node modules in my Expo app?

Comment: It would be helpful, if downvoters can also leave the reason to downvote, as well.

Comment: Please upvote here for expo mqtt support: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-mqtt-support

Answer (score 0):

in Expo, you can use any client based Javascript module, that you find in npm or that you created yourself.

But you can't use any kind of modules that has native parts in it. (Packages that you need to link to your react native projects can't be used) Although, Expo has its own SDK for your native needs.

The package you are talking about (mqtt.js) is a nodejs module, which can't be used with react native or in your case with Expo.

> Just a guess, if you are trying to have a browser in your react native or Expo project, react native has a builtin in-app browser you might want to check out; https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html